# How to attach file in importrows - fusion tables

Tags: php, google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I want to importRows to fusion table https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows

I'm using google-api-php-client and there's nothing about file in documentation (below).
How to attach file?

```
 /**
   * Import more rows into a table. (table.importRows)
   *
   * @param string $tableId
   * The table into which new rows are being imported.
   * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
   *
   * @opt_param int startLine
   * The index of the first line from which to start importing, inclusive. Default is 0.
   * @opt_param bool isStrict
   * Whether the CSV must have the same number of values for each row. If false, rows with fewer
    * values will be padded with empty values. Default is true.
   * @opt_param string encoding
   * The encoding of the content. Default is UTF-8. Use 'auto-detect' if you are unsure of the
    * encoding.
   * @opt_param string delimiter
   * The delimiter used to separate cell values. This can only consist of a single character. Default
    * is ','.
   * @opt_param int endLine
   * The index of the last line from which to start importing, exclusive. Thus, the number of
    * imported lines is endLine - startLine. If this parameter is not provided, the file will be
    * imported until the last line of the file. If endLine is negative, then the imported content will
    * exclude the last endLine lines. That is, if endline is negative, no line will be imported whose
    * index is greater than N + endLine where N is the number of lines in the file, and the number of
    * imported lines will be N + endLine - startLine.
   * @return Google_Service_Fusiontables_Import
   */
  public function importRows($tableId, $optParams = array())
  {
    $params = array('tableId' => $tableId);
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('importRows', array($params), "Google_Service_Fusiontables_Import");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can [see in the documentatio](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/table/importRows)n `importRows` excepts you to **upload** the file you want to import:

> This method supports an /upload URI and accepts uploaded media with
>   the following characteristics:
>
> - Maximum file size: 100MB
> - Accepted Media MIME types: application/octet-stream
>
> This method provides media upload functionality through two separate
>   URIs. For more details, see the document on media upload.
>
> - Upload URI, for media upload requests: POST
>     `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableId/import`
> - Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests: POST
>     `https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/tableId/import`

Now all you have to do is to upload your file to the corresponding URL.

[There](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/) [are](https://coderwall.com/p/fck2ta) [several](http://joshhighland.com/blog/2010/11/27/using-curl-and-php-to-upload-files-through-a-form-post/) tutorials that show you how to do this with PHP.